# Load gdb sources marked as "read on demand"

Tags: gdb, debug-symbols

I am debugging a C application (postgres) in GDB. When I hit a breakpoint, the top frame of the stack will always have source information, but lower frames often will not:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  findTargetlistEntrySQL99 (pstate=0x555555ef8f78, node=0x555555ef8c08, tlist=0x555555ef90d0, exprKind=EXPR_KIND_GROUP_BY) at /home/sergei/postgresql/src/backend/parser/parse_clause.c:1775
#1  0x00005555556c6e9d in findTargetlistEntrySQL92 (pstate=<optimized out>, node=<optimized out>, tlist=<optimized out>, exprKind=<optimized out>) at /home/sergei/postgresql/src/backend/parser/parse_clause.c:1744
#2  0x00005555556c72d5 in transformGroupClauseExpr (flatresult=flatresult@entry=0x7fffffffd0a0, seen_local=seen_local@entry=0x0, pstate=pstate@entry=0x555555ef8f78, gexpr=gexpr@entry=0x555555ef8c08, targetlist=targetlist@entry=0x555555ef90d0, sortClause=sortClause@entry=0x0, exprKind=EXPR_KIND_GROUP_BY, useSQL99=0 '\000', toplevel=1 '\001') at /home/sergei/postgresql/src/backend/parser/parse_clause.c:1970
#3  0x00005555556c9192 in transformGroupClause (pstate=0x555555ef8f78, grouplist=<optimized out>, groupingSets=0x555555ef90f0, targetlist=0x555555ef90d0, sortClause=0x0, exprKind=EXPR_KIND_GROUP_BY, useSQL99=0 '\000') at /home/sergei/postgresql/src/backend/parser/parse_clause.c:2287
#4  0x00005555556aa111 in transformStmt ()
#5  0x00005555556abe6d in parse_analyze ()
#6  0x000055555574c50e in DefineView ()
#7  0x0000555555867bda in ProcessUtilitySlow.isra.4 ()
#8  0x0000555555866a97 in standard_ProcessUtility ()
#9  0x0000555555864084 in PortalRunUtility ()
#10 0x0000555555864b95 in PortalRunMulti ()
#11 0x00005555558657a4 in PortalRun ()
#12 0x00005555558631f2 in exec_simple_query (query_string=0x555555ea6de0 "-- Statistics views\n\nCREATE VIEW pg_stat_all_tables AS\n    SELECT\n", ' ' <repeats 12 times>, "C.oid AS relid,\n", ' ' <repeats 12 times>, "N.nspname AS schemaname,\n", ' ' <repeats 12 times>, "C.relname AS relname,\n", ' ' <repeats 12 times>, "pg_stat_get_numscans(C."...) at /home/sergei/postgresql/src/backend/tcop/postgres.c:1094
#13 PostgresMain (argc=<optimized out>, argv=<optimized out>, dbname=<optimized out>, username=<optimized out>) at /home/sergei/postgresql/src/backend/tcop/postgres.c:4069
#14 0x00005555555f719d in main ()
```

At first, I suspected GDB could not find the source files for the lower frames. However, this is not the case: *info sources* shows these source files, but they are marked as "read on demand". For example, the function `DefineView` in frame 6 is defined in `view.c`.

```
(gdb) info sources
Source files for which symbols have been read in:
    ...
Source files for which symbols will be read in on demand:
    ... , /home/sergei/postgresql/src/backend/commands/view.c , ...
```

All source file paths (including `view.c`) are correct. **How can I get GDB to load these sources?** I am using GDB from an IDE, so solutions involving a one-off configuration change are preferrable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command line option gdb **--readnow**, should cause gdb to read symbol files as they are discovered.

Comment: For me, it is -readnow rather than --readnow that did the job.

Comment: I have already started my gdb session. When I enter `--readnow` or `-readnow` I get `Undefined command: "--readnow".  Try "help".` How can I require a readnow in the midst of an ongoing session?

Comment: @Viesturs I believe that you are entering --readnow at the (gdb) prompt, rather than passing it as an argument/command line option when starting gdb from the shell.

Comment: I had an unrelated issue, where I could add breakpoints to pending 'read on demand' source files only with relative paths. Absolute paths would work for read source files only. I spent days trying to tell CLion to use relative paths or trying to get gdb to understand the full paths. This flag fixed it!

Comment: @SergeiPatiakin, if you're adding the flag to gdb, then it's double dashes `gdb --readnow`. If you're adding the flag to the `file` command, then it's single `file a.out -readnow`.